# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module even if I use module scripts

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web

I've recently installed firebase from npm and I decided to change the imports from`import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.2/firebase-app.js"; import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.2/firebase-analytics.js";` to `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"; import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";`
And I got this error.
I've tried everything, but it didn't work.
Here's my script line.

```
<script src="javascript/home_page.mjs" type="module"></script>
```

If you have the solution to my problem, please answer me.

Comment: not clear about it

Comment: it an error about imports